# PHP syntax error when defining variable

Tags: php

I am using Yii-user module for authentication and I am trying to filter some output with user id.

```
class WordsController extends Controller
{
...
     private $userObject = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user();
...
}
```

This code shows this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in ...
```

I don't have an idea what is wrong.

Here is the link of the module https://code.google.com/p/yii-user/wiki/API

Comment: This is not really a Yii question as it is a pure PHP error. You should brush up on the PHP syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of the class property is invalid. This usage is not allowed by PHP.

```
private $userObject = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user();  // Invalid usage
```

To get around this, use the following :
class WordsController extends Controller

```
{
...
    private $userObject = null;

    public function init()
    {
       $this->userObject = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user();
    }
...
}
```

See the PHP manual for more details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php